# linq to sql gridview paging server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, gridview

I have table having large number of records which is bound to a Gridview. Currently it binds all the data at page load. I'm using following LINQ to SQL:

```
gvView.datasource = from c in _db.tblCategories
                        where c.bIsDeleted == false
                        select c;
gvView.databind();
```

I want to convert this with paging so that it doesn't show all the data at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `skip` and take `linq` methods. 
Please follow this link for example  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx

Here is a sample, but go through the link for better understanding

```
var custQuery2 =
    (from cust in db.Customers
    orderby cust.ContactName
    select cust)
    .Skip((currentpagenumber-1)*pagesize).Take(pagesize);
```

To use above code you need to change your approach. You need to to determine current page number and size based on user's selection, execute this code and rebind it to gridview.

Answer (score 0):

.CS Code

```
gvView.datasource = (from c in _db.tblCategories
                        where c.bIsDeleted == false
                        select c).ToList();
gvView.databind();
```

.ASPX Code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="myField1" HeaderText="myField1" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

See [This](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-Example.aspx) for GridView Pagination.